# How to migrate from typing.TypeAlias to type statements

Tags: python, python-typing

I have created a type alias for defining member variables in a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) through type annotations:

```
>>> from typing import TypeAlias
>>> Number: TypeAlias = int | float
>>> n, x = 1, 2.5
>>> isinstance(n, Number)
True
>>> isinstance(x, Number)
True
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias), this syntax has been deprecated:

> *Deprecated since version 3.12:* `TypeAlias` is deprecated in favor of the `type` statement, which creates instances of `TypeAliasType` and which natively supports forward references. Note that while `TypeAlias` and `TypeAliasType` serve similar purposes and have similar names, they are distinct and the latter is not the type of the former. Removal of `TypeAlias` is not currently planned, but users are encouraged to migrate to `type` statements.

I tried to use the new syntax, but I got an error:

```
>>> type Number = int | float
>>> isinstance(n, Number)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use `isinstance()` with type aliases. For instance, if you had `type intlist = list[int]`, testing if something is an instance would require iterating over all the list elements.

Comment: (to be clear, there _does exist_ tooling to actually do that iteration -- `pydantic` has the relevant ability, f/e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use `isinstance` with the new syntax, you need to access the type alias's value (and force its evaluation) explicitly, through the `__value__` attribute:

```
isinstance(n, Number.__value__)
```

Of course, this will only work if the value of the alias is compatible with `isinstance`, which rules out stuff like `NewType` or generics, or... most of the things you'd want to create a type alias for, but `int | float` should be fine. The old syntax had these limits too.